# How to find the length of the triangle's edge in this geometry question containing excenter?

Tags: geometry

[image: Two of edges' length is given. E is excenter point.]

This is geogebra output of a question from my textbook.It can be not to scale by the way.

> $B,D,F$ is linear. $E$ is the excenter. $EF$ is perpendicular to $[BF]$. In triangle $\triangle{ABD}$, $BE$ is the bisector of $\angle{ABD}$ and $DE$ is the bisector of $\angle{ADF}$. $|BD|=10$, $|AD|=8$ and $|DF|=5$. Find $|AB|.$

I tried to use bisector properties but i can't get the answer. I think we should use excenter. Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you give the exact question, as written because it's not clear what you mean by "BE and DE is bisector"? Also, what have you tried to solve this problem?

Comment: DE is bisector of ADF?

Comment: Sorry, i edited the question.

Comment: Maybe you should edit your picture instead.

Comment: Which part i should edit?

Comment: Enlarge it so that the given can be seen more clearly.

Comment: I think it is visible when clicked.

Comment: Didn't realize your picture can be magnified after click. Also, the necessary data have also been included in the edited version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given triangle $ABD$ and the excircle opposite angle $B$

Given $BF$ tangent to the excircle at $F$ and $BF=15$

$BA$ extended is tangent at $G$ and $BG=BF=15$. Therefore $AG=15-x$

$AD$ is tangent at $M$ with $AM=15-x$, $DM=5$, $AD=20-x=8$

$x=12$

**Note**: $x=AB$